# Oracle SYS_EXTRACT_UTC trying to understand

Tags: oracle

Here is one of our query in the database, i am trying to understand some UTC converstion in our query.

Can some one briefly explain, what the below query is doing?

```
SELECT 
 CAST (SYS_EXTRACT_UTC (CAST ( (BEGIN_DATE - (3 / 24)) AS TIMESTAMP)) AS DATE) BEGIN_DATE
FROM offer o
WHERE mask       = 'OK'
```

AFTER CONVERSION OUTPUT : 06-SEP-11 04:00:00

```
SELECT 
   BEGIN_DATE
FROM offer o
WHERE mask       = 'OK'
```

BEFORE CONVERSION OUTPUT : 06-SEP-11 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

`SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` extracts the `UTC` **(Coordinated Universal Time—formerly Greenwich Mean Time)** from a `datetime` value with `time zone offset` or `time zone region name`.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP '2014-11-05 12:00:00.00 -08:00') as dt
  2     FROM DUAL;

DT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
05-NOV-14 08.00.00.000000000 PM

SQL>
```

In your case, your timezone is `-08:00`. So, `-3/24` is used.

For example, my timezone is `+05:30`. The current time is,

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') dt from dual;

DT
----------------------
11/04/2014 01:12:21 pm

SQL>
```

The UTC time equivalent is,

```
SQL> SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP '2014-11-05 01:12:21.00 +05:30') as dt
  2     FROM DUAL;

DT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
04-NOV-14 07.42.21.000000000 PM

SQL>
```

Comment: See my edit, I explained it. 3/24 means, 8 hours. Your timezone is 8 hours behind. To deduct 8 hours from one day, you need to convert the hours into day units. So, 8 hours is `3/24` days.